# Calculate SHA256 sum of file quickly

Tags: c, sha

I have a piece of C code that takes as input a file and returns the SHAT256 hash of the contents:

```
int f_sha256(unsigned char* dest, char* filename){
  FILE* file;
  int read;
  int BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;
  char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
  EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
  const EVP_MD *md;
  unsigned int length;
  file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if(file <= 0){
    printf("%s\n", filename);
    perror("No file");
    return -1;
  }
  mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
  length = 0;
  OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
  md = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha256");
  EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
  while((read = fread((void*)buffer, 1, BUFFER_LENGTH, file)) != 0){
    EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, buffer, read);
    length += read;
    if(read < BUFFER_LENGTH){
      break;
    }
  }
  EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, dest, &length);
  EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(mdctx);
  EVP_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

It is VERY slow, according to valgrind 90% of the 5 seconds the entire program (there is other stuff involved, not relevant) is used in libcrypto, called from SHA256_Update. The function has no name (`0x00...006af80`), it is called 845 times, which I suppose is why it takes so much of the time.

However, if I run the command line sha256sum on the file, it finishes in around 0.05 seconds.

Why does using libcrypto take so long, how can I improve this performance?

Comment: I do, I read 1024 bytes at a time, I have tried this with different amounts ranging to 24k, it makes almost no difference

Comment: When you varied how much you read in at a time, did you also change how much you hash at a time?

Comment: Yes, you can see the number of bytes read being passed to EVP_DiggestUpdate

Comment: After calling f_sha256(), how do you know how many bytes were read into dest? EVP_DigestFinal_ex() returns the length, so perhaps you should do the same with f_sha256()

Comment: I know that it returns the correct hash, my concern is that it is so slow

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f100561e3fa87d29d549
I used your code pretty much verbatim and it runs fine for me

Comment: you are correct, it looks like valgrind was lying about the amount of time the SHA function was taking, the problem is elsewhere. Thanks for your help